# "definition of explicitly-defaulted" error with explicit template instantiation definition (Clang VS GCC)

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, extern, explicit-instantiation

Consider the following code:

```cpp
template <typename> struct S { S(); };
// extern template struct S<int>;
template <typename T> S<T>::S() = default;
template S<int>::S();
```

`clang++` happily accepts this code.

`g++` complains with:

```
error: definition of explicitly-defaulted 'S< <template-parameter-1-1> >::S() 
       [with <template-parameter-1-1> = int]'
    3 | template <typename T> S<T>::S() = default;
      |                       ^~~~
```

Uncommenting the `extern template` fixes compilation with `g++` (and `clang++` is still happy).

- [**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YoPhvKnxa)

**Is `g++` correct in rejecting the code?**

Comment: GCC is also happy with curly braces in lieu of `=default;` (as is Clang).

Comment: I don't see a reason for GCC to reject it.

Comment: File a bug against GCC?

Comment: Reported as: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=109387